# Jenkins pipeline, is there a way to set environment variable from console output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, veracode

My jenkinsfile containes two stages, build and upload&scan (veracode for static scans). My console output would contain somthing like: *build_id="21682834"* refers to veracode scan ID.

Can anyone help in finding this number and set it as environment variable?

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?  One approach is Veracode has rest api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code.

```
def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text

def buildId = (consoleLog =~ 'build_id="(.*)"')[0][1]
echo "build_id: $buildId"
env.build_id = buildId
```

Full Pipeline for testing.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Something"
                    echo "Something"
                    echo "Something"
                    echo "Something"
                    echo 'build_id="21682834"'
                    echo "Something"
                    echo "Something"
                    def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text

                    def buildId = (consoleLog =~ 'build_id="(.*)"')[0][1]
                    echo "build_id: $buildId"
                    env.build_id = buildId
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When the pipeline is under running,  I don't think it can get console output.

Comment: @yong, you can :) I added the Pipeline I tested the above code with, which worked fine.

Comment: that's great.   If Jenkins Script Approval configuration allow pipeline to invoke `Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber()`, your solution is perfect.

Comment: @ycr i got this error: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Job getBuildByNumber int

Comment: However this is the result that i get : ` build_id: 21682834" buildinfo_version="1.5" sandbox_id="*****" xsi:schemaLocation="https://analysiscenter.****** `

Comment: @Elian hope all your issues are sorted.