# Jenkins - Script to parse console output and set it as environment variable

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, veracode

I am into a scenario where I need to read the console output and find a specific string and set this as environment variable. This variable I would be using in input to run a different script in same job.

for example: my jenkins job's console would contain something like

build_id: 123456

Can somebody help in finding this number and pass it to input.environment variable to other script in same job?

I have looked into this answer but its not working, I am getting groovy errors while running it in post build groovy script.

[Jenkins pipeline, is there a way to set environment variable from console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74197785/jenkins-pipeline-is-there-a-way-to-set-environment-variable-from-console-output/75339985#75339985)

Script I am using:

```
import jenkins.model.*  
jenkins = Jenkins.instance  
def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text  
def buildId = (consoleLog =~ 'build_id="(.*)"')[0][1]  
echo "build_id: $buildId"  
env.build_id = buildId
```

Error I am getting:

```
ERROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script.
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: env for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
```

Comment: What is the error you get when running the code from the answer? Fixing that script to work for your code is your best option.

Comment: If all you need is a unique identifier you can use one of Jenkins' built in variables, like `BUILD_ID`, `BUILD_NUMBER`, `BUILD_TAG` etc.
If you absolutely must use a value from a script you can always consume the script's output using something like `def output = shell(script: './your-script.sh', readStdout: true)`, but first adapt the script to your needs as @MB suggests.

Comment: Hello @M B, this is the error I am getting :ERROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script.
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: env for class: Script1

Comment: Are you running your code as a Jenkins pipeline? According to [Using a Jenkinsfile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables), you should be able to use `env` to refer to environment variables. I say this because typically an error message like the one you got appears for when a variable is undefined.

Comment: I am not using jenkisnfile,  we just went with general configuration and  I am running this groovy script in post groovy script in jenkins job.

Comment: Do you mean you are using a post-build step? I am not sure Jenkins post-build steps define the `env` variable.

Comment: Are you using [postbuild-task](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuild-task/) or [postbuildscript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/) for the post-build step?

Comment: I am using groovy postbuild in post build actions to run above specified script and from there I am getting my build_id and then I am using this for another script.